# Powershell assigned access w/ kiosk browser

Tags: powershell, kiosk, kiosk-mode

Hello powershell gurus!

I was tasked to setup a kiosk machine that is locked down to a browser. I am trying to script the creation of a new local user on a machine that has the Kiosk Browser installed. I then want to use AssignedAccess to force the account into kiosk mode with Kiosk Browser. Finally, I would enable autologin to force it to log into that new local user

This is the part of the script I am using to setup the user and assigned access

```
New-LocalUser -Name $_.Username -Password ($_.Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force)
Set-AssignedAccess -AppUserModelID Microsoft.KioskBrowser_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App -UserName $_.Username
```

I keep getting the following error with the AssignedAccess portion:

```
New-CimInstance : One or more parameter values passed to the method were invalid.
At C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\AssignedAccess\AssignedAccess.psm1:310 char:13
+             New-CimInstance -ClassName WEDL_AssignedAccess -Property  ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (WEDL_AssignedAccess:CimInstance) [New-CimInstance], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MI RESULT 4,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.NewCimInstanceCommand
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure how far you are into this project, but locking down a machine to a browser is actually a very complicated thing. There are multiple pieces of kiosk software that provide a full screen browser that is already fully secured (full disclosure: I work at a company that makes one of them). Then you can focus on the web pages for the kiosk content.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling -  i am pretty deep in at this point haha. an in-house solution is really what i'm after, using a combination of Intune deployments and Powershell